# How to find all inputs with values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

The goal is to list ALL the values for all the inputs on the page, but not list inputs that do not have values, two question:

```
$(":input").not("[id*=a_prefix_]").map(function() 
    { 
        var value = this.val(); 
        if( value ) console.log(this.id + ":=" + value ); 
    }
);
```

1. There is an issue with the this.val(), I get an error "Object doesn't support property or method 'val'", what is the solution?
2. How do I move the check to see if there is a value into the actual selection so that the map only gets inputs with values?

Comment: `this.value` or `$(this).val()`.  And use `each()` instead of `map()` as it doesn't look like you are trying to translate anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var valueArray = $(":input")
    // filter these things out, whatever they are
    .not("[id*=a_prefix_]")
    // filter only the elements that have a value
    .filter(function(){ return this.value.trim(); })
    // map the values
    .map(function(){ return {[this.id]: this.value}; })
    // turn the results into a real array, not a jQuery object of the values
    .get();
```

Comment: so I understand the filter, my only question is regarding the map/get(), it looks like you are returning an array of the values, but I need to return something that looks like this: id := value, do I simply change the map to return this.id + ":=" + this.value?

Comment: @aphotographer updated answer to return an object with the id as the key